# SFTP - connection was aborted (C#)

Tags: c#, connection, sftp, abort

I have tool which download files from sftp. This tool working for 2 years but now it stop working. Error received is:

```
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

Host machine is on customer site and it is very complicated to get any log from HOST. I would like to ask you what is possible reasons.

Here is log from my tool:

```
2016-05-24 12:00:00,887 DEBUG [1] LoggingManager:0 Using key authentification, private key file: 'C:\Programme\PMS\SCPCopy\unionkey\pmsui_keyfile.id'.
2016-05-24 12:00:01,027 DEBUG [1] LoggingManager:0 Connecting to server: '1.1.1.1' port: '22'
2016-05-24 12:00:01,043 DEBUG [1] SSHDotNetSftpProvider:0 Connect...
2016-05-24 12:00:01,043 DEBUG [1] BaseClient:0 Connect
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 Attempt to create new session for the following connection info:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 Host: 1.1.1.1
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 Port: 22
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 Username: XXXXX
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ProxyType: None
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ProxyHost:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ProxyPort: 0
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ProxyUsername:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ProxyPassword:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 RetryAttempts: 10
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 Encoding: System.Text.UTF8Encoding
2016-05-24 12:00:01,058 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 MaxSessions: 10
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 KeyExchangeAlgorithm:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ServerEncryption:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ClientEncryption:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ServerHmacAlgorithm:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ClientHmacAlgorithm:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 HostKeyAlgorithm:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ServerCompressionAlgorithm:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ClientCompressionAlgorithm:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ServerVersion:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] ConnectionInfo:0 ClientVersion:
2016-05-24 12:00:01,074 DEBUG [1] BaseClient:0 Attempt to create new session
2016-05-24 12:00:01,090 DEBUG [1] Session:0 Wait for the connection authentication
2016-05-24 12:00:01,105 DEBUG [1] Session:0 GetMessagesMetadata
2016-05-24 12:00:01,105 DEBUG [1] Session:0 Proxy type: None
2016-05-24 12:00:01,105 DEBUG [1] Session:0 Host: 1.1.1.1
2016-05-24 12:00:01,105 DEBUG [1] Session:0 Port: 22
2016-05-24 12:00:01,152 DEBUG [1] Session:0 ConnectionInfo: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
2016-05-24 12:00:01,152 DEBUG [1] Session:0 ClientVersion: SSH-2.0-Renci.SshNet.SshClient.0.0.1
2016-05-24 12:00:01,152 DEBUG [1] Session:0 Server version: 2.0
2016-05-24 12:00:01,152 DEBUG [1] Session:0 Software name: OpenSSH_7.2
2016-05-24 12:00:01,277 DEBUG [1] LoggingManager:0 An error occured: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

For sftp connection is used Renci.SshNet (version 2013.4.7)

Comment: Have you tried running the code locally / debugging it ..? also how can we see what's going on if you don't show the code that pertains to the actual issue..?

Comment: You might also include the libraries you are using to Achieve SFTP since its not something supported "out of the box" in .Net, that is unless you  implemented something yourself.

Comment: My local test working - tool stop working on customer side which is black box me. Not able to connect customer env. or host which customer using. I dont think that we can find solution just with this info. I would like to know to have some check list what is possibilities for this fail.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in  Renci.SshNet (version 2013.4.7). This version was able to communicate with SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7 but not with SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2.

Actual version of Renci.SshNet solved this issue.